# Edge 40/15 opacity/visibility transition event propagation (flickering) bug?

Tags: html, css, less, css-transitions, microsoft-edge

In older versions of Edge, the desired transition effect works correctly.
I am simply animating a div by transitioning opacity/visibility with CSS when its parent's hover event is called.

```
//LESS
&:hover .inside{
  //part that matters:
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1.0;
  transition-delay:0s;
}
.inside{
  //part that matters:
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s linear 1s,opacity 1s ease;
}
//Pug
.wrapper
  .button text
    .inside more text
```

The problem.

In Chrome, IE 11, and Edge 25 the transition is consistent and correct.  However, the transition events seem to be stacking up and making the opacity jump back and forth if I hover over or leave the button before the transitions complete naturally.
Here's an example of it: https://codepen.io/vtsells/pen/RZjLYP


Is this a bug or am I missing something?  I find it odd that older versions of Edge work correctly

Comment: Why are you setting the transition delay on the hover selector anyways?

Comment: But strangely enough, the problem reappears if you completly remove that property...

Comment: So that the visibility is set to true instantly when the show transition begins and waits until the hide transition is done before it sets back to hidden

Comment: Can't you just set `visibility 1s` without any delay on `.inside`? I can't test it on Windows, but it works on Chrome/Mac

Comment: In testing, yes you can but you still have to change the transition-delay to 0.1s or else the problem persists, like Daniel mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `transition-delay:0s` is causing the problems. Setting it to a very low value should give you a good result: `transition-delay: 0.01s`

Here's your working [codepen](https://codepen.io/Loxos/pen/xLYKma).

Comment: You're a genius!  Is there a logical reason as to why this solved the issue or is it just a quirk?

Comment: Actually, I have no clue why this happens and I'm sure it is some weird quirk. It should be possible to omit `transition-delay` completely, but then the flickering reappears...